# How to invoke a function which is defined as a field of a record in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have the following record which has a function type as a field type.

```ballerina
public type ReadFunction function (string id) returns anydata|error;

public type WriteFunction function (string id, anydata data) returns error?;

public type SourceInteraction record {|
    ReadFunction read;
    WriteFunction write;
|};
```

I have tried to invoke the function using the record like this,

```ballerina
public function write(SourceInteraction interaction, string id, anydata data)
        returns error? {
            
    check interaction.write(id, data);
}
```

But I am getting this error when trying to invoke the function like the above:
`function invocation on type 'SourceInteraction' is not supported`

Answer (score 1):

Here the error is expected as Ballerina does not support directly calling the function that is a field of a record using the method call syntax. We need to assign it to a variable first and use the function call syntax with it.

```ballerina
public function write(SourceInteraction interaction, string id, anydata data)
        returns error? {

    WriteFunction write = interaction.write;
    check write(id, data);
}
```